# Check for existence of function in function closure by string

Tags: javascript, node.js, closures

Within a JavaScript `async function` I want to check if a certain function is available in its closure environment.

The function is available. I can execute it explicitly, or do `console.log(myClosureScopedFunc)`.

But when the name of the function is inside a string variable, how can I see if it exists in the closure?

- In the `async function`, `this` is undefined, otherwise I could do `if (this['myClosureScopedFunc']) // gotcha`
- For some probably obvious reason, I cannot do `self = this` in the same scope as `myClosureScopedFunc` either because `self` will be `undefined` in the `async function` too.
- `eval('myClosureScopedFunc')` works, but I don't want to use `eval` for reasons.

---

**Minimalistic `express` code example**

The route (function to look for) is defined in `req.params.route`.

```
'use strict'

module.exports = async function(req, res, next) {
    try {
        if (this[req.params.route].length === 3) // THIS DOES NOT WORK
            return await this[req.params.route](req, res, next)
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log(err.stack)
        return res.status(404).end(err.message)
    }
}

async function myClosureScopedFunc(req, res, next) {
    return await "some async data"
}
```

---

### Here is the answer

Edited into the question because it was closed as a duplicate for a semi-related case. In case someone ends up here through google, here is how you do it specifically inside the Node.js `module` context.

My initial second thought (second point above) was right, but as commenter @Bergi pointed out, the `this` keyword scopes methods.

So every function needs to be added to the `exports` object. Then we can use it as intended:

```
'use strict'

const self = this // scope the module
exports.myClosureScopedFunc = myClosureScopedFunc // Add to scope

module.exports = async function(req, res, next) {
    try {
        if (self[req.params.route].length === 3)
            return await self[req.params.route](req, res, next)
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log(err.stack)
        return res.status(404).end(err.message)
    }
}

async function myClosureScopedFunc(req, res, next) {
    return await "some async data"
}
```

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with `async`/`await`. It's the same in a normal function.

Comment: JS uses lexical scoping. You don't have to check whether it is available at runtime. You know at compile time (and during implementation) whether or not it is in scope! What is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)? It sounds like you really are looking for `eval`, so please explain how the thing you want is different from `eval`.

Comment: @Bergi you are right. It's not available in non-async either. I misjudged that. Why is there no `this` in this function?

Comment: Nothing special about `this` in `async function`s vs normal `function`s either. If `this` is not the value you expect, you're not invoking the function as a method.

Comment: Thank you @Bergi, you helped me figure out the answer. I've added it above; since the question is locked, I cannot post it as an answer.

Comment: I cannot recommend to use `self = this` and then assign to `exports.myProperty`. Either use `self = exports`, no `self` variable at all (only `exports`), or - much better - just `self = {myProperty: …};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions defined on a module, are not exposed to the `global` object, so to access those functions by name, you will need to store them inside an object.

In the following snippet, a `funcs` object is defined, that contains the private functions, that cannot be accessed from outside this module, since `funcs` is never exported.

```js
function require() {

  const funcs = {
    async myClosureScopedFunc(req, res, next) {
      return await "some async data"
    }
  };
  
  // or
  // funcs.myClosureScopedFunc = async function(...) {}
  
  return async function exportedFunc(name) {
      if(funcs[name])
          console.log(await funcs[name]());
      else
        console.log('nop');
  }
}

const x = require();

x('imNotAFunction');
x('myClosureScopedFunc');
```